# How to get the Primary key after insert in SQL Ce For windows phone

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

Ado.net is not in Windows phone, so how do I get the primary key after an Insert operation?

There is the method in SQL:

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

So, for SQl Ce in Windows phone, How to do it with Linq To SQL or whatever.

Thanks

---Updated :

Is this the  onInsert  you refer in the column ?

```
[Column(Storage="_CtcId", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
public int CtcId
{
    get
    {
        return this._CtcId;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._CtcId != value))
        {
            this.OnCtcIdChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._CtcId = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("CtcId");
            this.OnCtcIdChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the return ID. Please advise if this is the correct way to get primary key after insert operation such as this:

```
using (DBContacts context = new DBContacts(ConnectionString))
                    {
                        //--- create object first:

                        TblContacts tblCtc = new TblContacts();


                        tblCtc.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
                        tblCtc.LastName =txtLastName.Text.Trim();
                        tblCtc.Birthday = txtBirthday.Text.Trim();
                        tblCtc.NickName = txtNickName.Text.Trim();

                context.TblContacts.InsertOnSubmit(tblCtc);
                        context.SubmitChanges();

                        var id = tblCtc.CtcId;

                        MessageBox.Show("Inserted Ok. Id is no :" + id.ToString());


                    }
```

Comment: If it works, then yes it's the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objects PrimaryKey property have [AutoSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.autosync.aspx) set to OnInsert , then once you inserted a object, the object will automatically have it's key updated.

Example:

```
var newPerson = new Person() { Name = "Windcape" };
people.Add(newPerson);

var id = newPerson.Id; // Id is now the inserted id
```

Comment: Claus: Wow. It is short and simple but I am not sure as have been used to the old way. please see my code above.